# Find Control in javascript by using variable

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, findcontrol

i have to Hide/Unhide panel of asp web form by javascript. pls Help

```
for (var l = 1; l <= ddlSizesValue; l++) 
  {
        var Size = "pnlProduct1Design1Color1Size" + l;
        var pnl = document.getElementById('pnlProduct')
       var pnlSize = document.getElementById(Size);
        pnlSize.style.display = 'block';            
   }
```

before javascript i was using

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl pnlSize = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl)pnlProduct.FindControl(Size);
```

in c# to find control and it was working fine. but to avoid page load i am using javascripting.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done it by changing variable size to:

```
  var Size = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucSetProduct1Detail_pnlProduct1Design1Color1Size" + l;
```

now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

To hide an element in Javascript you would normally do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("pnlProduct").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: pnlProduct is the ID of the panel.
In var Size i have inserted ID of another Panel which i want to show/Hide Which is inside 'pnlProduct '